# Error: Invalid sample cursor, or sample out of range reported for iOS custom audio track

Tags: ios, swift, avassetexportsession, avmutablecomposition

As long as I add the original audio track in the video, an error "Invalid sample cursor, or sample out of range" will be reported when exporting.

```
var audioInputParams: [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters] = []
for audioTrack in audioTracks {
    guard let track = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) else {
        continue
    }
    let audioTimeRange: CMTimeRange = .init(start: .zero, duration: audioTrack.timeRange.duration)
    try track.insertTimeRange(audioTimeRange, of: audioTrack, at: .zero)
    track.preferredTransform = audioTrack.preferredTransform
    let audioInputParam = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: track)
    audioInputParam.setVolumeRamp(fromStartVolume: factor.volume, toEndVolume: factor.volume, timeRange: audioTimeRange)
    audioInputParam.trackID = track.trackID
    audioInputParams.append(audioInputParam)
}
```

When I decrease the duration of audioTimeRange by 1 second it just works fine

```
let audioTimeRange: CMTimeRange = .init(start: .zero, duration: .init(seconds: audioTrack.timeRange.duration.seconds - 1, preferredTimescale: audioTrack.timeRange.duration.timescale))
```

Some videos are normal, and some videos are wrong. I checked the timeRange of the video track vs the audio track, they are all the same
The video of the error is here: [Video](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/fe913637cc3457648fdfcc87809b588420230716160010/d7668e)

I've searched a lot, but no one has the same error as me